# Export instance of class A as well as nested class A.B

Tags: typescript

I have a class `A` of which I want to export an instance. `A` has a method that returns an instance of `A.B`. Can I export both the instance and static inner class somehow?

```
class A {
    public static B = class {}

    getB(): A.B { // <- compile error
        return new A.B(); // this works fine
    }
}

export default new A();
export { A.B }
```

I'm coming from a Java background and as you can see I'm struggling a bit here to make the switch. I'm guessing I am supposed to do something with modules instead?

Here's how I would like to use it:

```
import a from "./A";
import { A.B }  from "./A";

let b: A.B = a.getB();
```

Comment: Why make it an "inner class" then?

Comment: @NitzanTomer I want to imply that the two classes really belong together, while maintaining a structural separation of the data.

Comment: This approach will only bring you pain. Typescript is very different than java in this so you shouldn't think in the same way... For example, the inner class won't have any access to the members of the outer class. You gain nothing by embedding it.  Also, what's the point in exporting only an instance of `A` and not the class? Is it a singleton?

Comment: @NitzanTomer isn't that how a lot of libraries work, by exposing an instance? It should be an singleton (or rather it makes no sense to have multiple instances). B doesn't have to be a nested class, I'm more interested in semantically expressing the relationship between A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting the classes was a java reflex, but what I really wanted to express is the close relationship between A and B and where the code is managed for both.

Modifying [@NitzanTomer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44057541/441662), here's what worked for me:

```
class A {
  getB(): B {
    return new B();
  }
}

export class B {
}

export default new A();
```

Then usage is simple:

```
import a from './my-library';
import {B} from './my-library';

let b: B = a.getB();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need more than one instance of `A`, then maybe it shouldn't be a class...
How about this approach:

```
class B { }

const singleton = {
    getB(): B {
        return new B();
    }
};

export default singleton;
```

Comment: Javascript isn't OO as java, you can have an object with methods and members without having a class for it. If you only need one instance and you don't need inheritance then having a class is redundant. I'm not sure what you mean by "merging A and B". If you explain more what your situation is I can clarify my approach, or agree that it's not appropriate.

Comment: This won't work, because class B is not exported. I can not declare a variable of type B. Is something like this possible?

export { B };
export default singleton;